# MS Structured Query Language

Tags: mysql

I need a query for this scenario, I have a same column name as **date_updated** in **three or four tables** I need to retrieve the rows from 3 tables which updated on yesterday or today. ***Simply saying if I run this query it  need to retrieve all the rows which updated yesterday or today along with updated date from all the tables.***

Please tell me the way to do that.

Comment: give proper information , or whatever you tried.

Comment: Either use a Union ALL to get output row by row or Union all in a subquery with case statements outside subquery to get 1 row output.

Comment: Do you mean 'MS' or 'MY'?

Comment: Which one? MS or MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have 4 tables   use union all

```
(select * from table a where date_updated=?)
union all 
(select * from table b where date_updated=?)
union all 
(select * from table c where date_updated=?)
union all 
(select * from table d where date_updated=?)
```